# How to include a URL/link to a FaceTime number in a programmed SMS

Tags: javascript, html, sms, twilio, facetime

We want to SMS our users with a message containing a link that they can click in an iOS device that will automatically go to FaceTime and call that number.  We already have a javascript function setup that will send an SMS message to the user through Twilio:

```
srvTwilioService.sendSMS(phone, message);
```

What should the content of the message look like so that what the user receives has a clickable html link that contains a phone number so that when the user clicks it they are automatically placed into a FaceTime call to the number, e.g. something of the logical form:

```
var msg = '<a href="facetime:14085551234">Connect using FaceTime</a>';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

[SMS messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message) don't include a notion of markup, so you can't use the anchor tag like you've shown, but I did try just including the text `facetime://15555555555` and the Messages app did recognize that text as a link and tapping did deep link me into the facetime app.

Hope that helps